# Python - Openpyxl - Add formula to column and repeat formula to last row of data

Tags: python, excel, formula, openpyxl

Trying to do the following:
In column G add the following formula:
`"=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-D2)) *COS(RADIANS(90-D3)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-D2)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-D3)) *COS(RADIANS(E2-E3))) *6371"`

Repeat this formula in column G up to the last row with data in columns D and E.
I want the cells in the formula to update as formula goes down the rows (i.e. D2 becomes D3...)

Tried the following without success. This will copy the formula in all the rows for column G with data in columns D and E but I am missing the part to update the D and E cells in the formula for each row. My script is incomplete and don't know how to fix it.

````
for row_num in range(3, max_row+1):
    sheet['G{}'.format(row_num)] = '=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-D2)) *COS(RADIANS(90-D3)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-D2)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-D3)) *COS(RADIANS(E2-E3))) *6371'.format(row_num)```
````

Comment: I am new with Python but I just figured it out.  The following works.

```for row_num in range(3, max_row+1):
    sheet['G{}'.format(row_num)] = '=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-D{})) *COS(RADIANS(90-D{})) +SIN(RADIANS(90-D{})) *SIN(RADIANS(90-D{})) *COS(RADIANS(E{}-E{}))) *6371'.format(row_num-1, row_num, row_num-1, row_num, row_num-1, row_num)```

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question then post this as an answer, and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new with Python but I just figured it out. The following works.

`for row_num in range(3, max_row+1):     sheet['G{}'.format(row_num)] = '=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-D{})) *COS(RADIANS(90-D{})) +SIN(RADIANS(90-D{})) *SIN(RADIANS(90-D{})) *COS(RADIANS(E{}-E{}))) *6371'.format(row_num-1, row_num, row_num-1, row_num, row_num-1, row_num)`

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the function provided by `openpyxl` to translate formulas:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html#translating-formulae-from-one-location-to-another

```py
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

formula_translator = Translator(
    "=ACOS("
    "COS(RADIANS(90-D2))*COS(RADIANS(90-D3))"
    "+SIN(RADIANS(90-D2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-D3))*COS(RADIANS(E2-E3))"
    ")*6371",
    origin="G2",
)

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    sheet[f"G{row}"] = formula_translator.translate_formula(f"G{row}")
```